# how can a gaze "whisper"

Tags: verbs

What is the meaning of the verb "whisper" in the sentence below?

> Her gaze ***whispered*** down the white cotton spread tight over a sinewy chest and wide shoulder.

[Source](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MqefAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT19&dq=%22gaze%20whispered%20down%20the%20white%20cotton%20spread%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PaQYVMiYGYjoaNqMgegM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22gaze%20whispered%20down%20the%20white%20cotton%20spread%22&f=false) C. C. Hunter, *Reborn* (2014)

Comment: Where did this sentence come from? That's often [helpful information](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), and worth including, even if you think your question can be answered without it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is effectively Literary Criticism.

Comment: Another question put on hold. Again, FF's initiation lead to gather masses. We are non-native speakers and LEARNERS who **do not understand** literary criticism and that is why the question is here. Polite and better way to address this is what Teircelet did. If you have knowledge, spread it and if you are incapable to answer, let others answer and you *learn!*.

Comment: When I hear the word *gaze*, what comes to mind is how a woman looks with her eyes when she is trying to entice someone.  To me it connotes dreaming about having something as well - you gaze at something, you want it, one could say you are trying to summon it to you with your eyes.  So it would seem a *gaze* could in a poetic sense speak to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is strictly poetic/literary usage. The word does not literally fit at all, because people cannot actually make a sound (even a quiet one!) just by looking at something with their eyes.

In this context, "whisper" is used because it suggests quietness, softness, and intimacy. You have to be very close to whisper successfully. The word choice is probably also influenced by the use of "whisper" to describe the sound made by rustling fabric. It would be not uncommon to say that the white cotton "whispered" in the breeze, or something like that.

Comment: I'm not sure if the _sound_ of a whisper needs to be involved with a "literal" use of the word "whisper". It's a judgment call, I suppose. Phrases like _whisper of smoke_ or _whisper of color_ aren't alluding to a soft sound. The word "whisper" can also be used to mean a hint or trace of something.

Comment: That's a good point, but I think it applies to the noun more than the verb.

Comment: I won't argue with you there. That's two good points now between us. :^)

Comment: I think the question's OT anyway, but noting the context (apparently, two vampires "sizing each other up") it seems likely the "secret, furtive" associations of *whispering* are more relevant here than "quietness, softness, intimacy".

Comment: @FF fair; I'd answered before the OP provided the source. It's likely to be OT in the sense that it's lit-crit, but it is also a word meaning question that's decidedly unanswerable with a dictionary, so I figured it could stay... especially as it stresses the fluidity of linguistic categories, which is something ELLs should be aware of & aren't reminded of often enough.

Comment: This strikes me as a word usage or vocabulary question, not a literary criticism question. We're being asked to help interpret the meaning of a word, not a book.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like the use of *whisper* in this context. Whisper should allow the reader to infer a form of subtle communication, not a rate of movement.

"Her gaze *whispered her intentions as it lingered* down the white cotton spread tight over a sinewy chest and wide shoulder."

Comment: Lingered on, not lingered down.

Answer (score 0):

This  kind of writing is known derogatorily as "purple prose". Are you sure the original has singular "shoulder", BTW?

"Whisper" is meant to imply "moving gently", but it's a mixed metaphor, hardly the *mot juste*.

Comment: As to the singular shoulder: She is staring at two pieces of meat - a chest and a shoulder (I'm thinking of lamb now) - wrapped in white cotton for some reason. I guess her obvious intentions are to unwrap it, cook it and eat it. She obviously is hungry!

Comment: LOL.  The original page wasn't displaying. Now it is. It should be plural, "wide shoulders".  The singular does suggest  a carnivorous gaze. `"You are trespassing on Shadow Falls property," she barked.` :-)